# Why does my grammar rule cause an error, just because I changed the casing of the rule name?

Tags: antlr4

I copy the antlr4 json grammar from here: [grammar json](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/json)

and I modified some rule and the code as below:

```
grammar PyJson;

my_rule
   : STRING
   ;

waha
   : STRING
   | INT
   ;

STRING
   : '"' (ESC | SAFECODEPOINT)* '"'
   ;
fragment ESC
   : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE)
   ;

fragment UNICODE
   : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX
   ;

fragment HEX
   : [0-9a-fA-F]
   ;

fragment SAFECODEPOINT
   : ~ ["\\\u0000-\u001F]
   ;

fragment INT
   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*
   ;

WS
   : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip
   ;
```

I use the my_rule to test "helloWorld", and it runs well. But if change the rule "waha" to "WAHA", it throws an error.

```
[@0,0:11='"helloWorld"',<WAHA>,1:0]
[@1,20:19='<EOF>',<EOF>,5:0]
line 1:0 mismatched input '"helloWorld"' expecting STRING
```

why the grammar rule runs error just because I change the case of rule? could you help me please? thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule names starting with an upper case letter are automatically considered to be lexer rules, otherwise they are parser rules. With your change you converted `waha` to a lexer rule with an own token type (`<WAHA>`). This is not the `STRING` type which `my_rule` expects, hence the syntax error.

Comment: After I have read your words many times, I still have not understood. I found that when I move the STRING rule before WAHA, even if WAHA is upper case, it seems running well.  but it confused me, according to my understanding, antlr4 runs the grammar tree rule from top to bottom. so I think it runs from `my_rule` -> `STRING`, isn't it have nothing to do with `WAHA`? I'm newer for antlr4, could you please explain it clearly, thank you Mike very much!

Comment: Moving `STRING` before the `WAHA` rule, matches the `STRING` rule and returns the `STRING` token, which is what the parser `my_rule` expects. That's why it works that way. Keep in mind that rules, which match the same input (here `STRING` and `WAHA`) are resolved by using the one which appears first in the grammar.